Pythonic way to create a singleton class that requires an async method to setup?
I'm writing a Python package that implements a class which should be a singleton.
The class is responsible for sending async http requests. Thus the class needs to have access to an aiohttp.ClientSession.
The catch is that I wish to support two types of instantiation:

The user can supply the ClientSession as a parameter during instantiation.
If the user doesn't supply a session, the class should create one.

class AsyncFoo:
    client_session: aiohttp.ClientSession

    def __init__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Direct instantion is not allowed. Use `AsyncFoo.create()`.")

    @classmethod
    async def create(cls, session: None | aiohttp.ClientSession = None):
        instance = cls.__new__(cls)
        if session is None:
            instance.client_session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
        else:
            instance.client_session = session
        return instance

    async def send_request(self):
        self.client_session.post("url")

What is the best way to ensure that this class is a Singleton?
Please be aware that this class is meant to be part of a package, so creating an instance inside the package and then referencing it does not seem like a solution to me (at least from this standpoint).

With a singleton, if the object has already been created, it should simply return the already created object without modification.

"What is the best way to ensure that this class is a Singleton?" there is no good way to do that in Python, and you never really need to

In python, almost anywhere you would really want to use a singleton in a language like, say, Java, you'd just use a module. That module can contain implementation details, like a class, and you simply expose methods that manipulate the module global state.
